# C# Guessing Game using a text file

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

I'm trying to create a word guessing game that uses a dictionary text file. The game is supposed to take input from the user on how long the word should be before asking them to guess the word. If the user fails to guess after 3 times then it reveals the answer. I used a list on recommendation from a friend to read from the dictionary as it is quite large.

My question is, how can I read the list to choose a word for the guessing game?

```
{
    static int letterLength, LettersLeft, wrongGuess;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string input = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("dictionary.txt");
        string[] terms = input.Split();

        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        for (int num = 0; num < terms.Length; num++)
            list.Add(terms[num]);

        int wordToGuess = GetLengthOfWordToGuess();

        List<string> fixedlist = new List<string>();
        for (int num = 0; num < list.Count; num++)
        {
            string tempword = list[num];

            if (tempword.Length == wordToGuess)
                fixedlist.Add(tempword);
        }

        for (int num = 0; num < fixedlist.Count; num++)
            Console.WriteLine(fixedlist[num]);


        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the guessing game");

        letterLength = GetLengthOfWordToGuess();

        Console.Clear();

//Not Working from here on.

        string wordGuess = GetWordToGuess();
        char[] maskedWord = GetHiddenLetters(wordGuess, '-');
        LettersLeft = wordGuess.Length;
        char userGuess;
        wrongGuess = 3;

        while (wrongGuess > 0 && LettersLeft > 0)
        {
            DispayCharacters(maskedWord);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a Letter");
            userGuess = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            maskedWord = CheckGuess(userGuess, wordGuess, maskedWord);

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Well done! Thanks for Playing.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
    static string GetWordToGuess()
    {

        Random word = new Random();
        int wordNumber = word.Next(0, 9);
        string[] words = { "" };
        string selectWord = words[wordNumber];
        return selectWord;


    }

    static char [] GetHiddenLetters(string word, char mask)
    {
        char[] hidden = new char[word.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            hidden[i] = mask;
        }
        return hidden;
    }
    static void DispayCharacters(char [] characters)
    {
        foreach(char letter in characters)
        {
            Console.Write(letter);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    static int GetLengthOfWordToGuess()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input length of word to guess");
        int selectWord = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return selectWord;
    }

    static char [] CheckGuess (char letterToCheck, string word, char [] characters)
    {
        bool wrong = true;
        if(wrongGuess > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {
                if (word[i] == letterToCheck)
                {
                    characters[i] = word[i];
                    LettersLeft--;
                    wrong = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: What does "/Not Working from here on." mean?

Comment: As a note for future questions you want to post here's some quick tips. 1. Leave out the greeting, I know it sounds nice, but it just gets in the way of people getting to your actual question. 2. Before posting your question, try debugging into the program and seeing if you can find the problem (or at least narrow down the problem). 3. Include a portion of referenced files (in your case dictionary.txt). 4. It is helpful if you state your question clearly so that people know what you are looking for (or rephrase it to be a question as I have done in an edit for you)

Comment: How many words in your dictionary file?

Comment: Please read [How To Debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

One major problem I see up front is that your `GetWordToGuess` function is not functional and probably throws an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. 
The reason for that is that you are instantiating the words array as an array with a single empty string in it, but you are then referencing an index between 0 and 9, which will not exist in that array unless the random number generated is 0.

To solve this you should pass the `fixedlist` List you already created and use that instead of the `words` array. You should make sure to generate a random number between 0 and `fixedlist.Count-1` so that you don't hit that same out of range exception. Therefore that function should look something like this:

```
    static string GetWordToGuess(List<string> fixedlist)
    {

        Random word = new Random();
        int wordNumber = word.Next(0, 9);
        string[] words = { "" };
        string selectWord = words[wordNumber];
        return selectWord;
    }
```

Also, as it stands right now, your included code doesn't compile because the `CheckGuess` function doesn't return a `char[]` as it says it should. I believe what you meant to do was have a `return characters;` line at the end (this was probably just a copy paste issue when you put your code in your question, but I thought I'd mention it just in case).

As a side note there are a number of small issues with your code like declaring things you don't use, but since they don't break your program I didn't want to go through and fix them.